# <div> tag to <img> tag Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hello is it possible to change div tags to image tags?

I tried using this

```
var testDivTags= document.getElementsByClassName('div_tags');
var testImgTag= document.createElement("img");

for (var i = 0; i < testDivTags.length; ++i) {
    testDivTags[i].parentNode.replaceChild(testImgTag, testDivTags[i])      
}
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't work **HOW**?

Comment: I dont think u can do that

Comment: create a <div> container and then u can insert an image in it

Comment: Nothing happens to my div it stays the same T_T

Comment: Seems to work perfectly fine, the problem does not lie with the code you provided. http://jsfiddle.net/bw7mdmtg/ (Inspect element will reveal that an  `img` has replaced the `div`.)

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  There is likely little need to swap markup like this in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an element can't be at different places in the DOM simultaneously.

Instead, you should [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) the element, and insert the clones:

```js
parent.replaceChild(newChild.cloneNode(), oldChild)
```

Moreover, there is another problem: the `HTMLCollection` returned by `getElementsByClassName` is live. Therefore, when you replace the elements, they disappear from the list, and following ones are reindexed to lower indices. To fix that, you can

- Iterate the live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) collection backwards:

  ```js
  var liveC = document.getElementsByClassName('div_tags');
  for (var i = liveC.length-1; i >= 0; --i)
      liveC[i].parentNode.replaceChild(testImgTag.cloneNode(), liveC[i]);
  ```
- Convert it to an array:

  ```js
  var array = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('div_tags'));
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
      array[i].parentNode.replaceChild(testImgTag.cloneNode(), array[i]);
  ```
- Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), which returns a static [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) collection:

  ```js
  var staticC = document.querySelectorAll('.div_tags');
  for (var i = 0; i < staticC.length; ++i)
      staticC[i].parentNode.replaceChild(testImgTag.cloneNode(), staticC[i]);
  ```